# how to get rid of google preference script?

Tags: javascript, safari, preferences

I always see this in the source code of my Browser Safari, although it is not part of the page's source code - it's like Safari always places it in front of the rest.

```
<script type="text/javascript">window["_gaUserPrefs"] = { ioo : function() { return true; } }</script>
```

I read somewhere that it is used to send preferences of browsing behavior to Google, but I don't whether any of that is true.

In any case: how can I get rid of it?

Thanks!

Dennis

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's the browser extension that will cause it.

https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout

To get rid of that line, make sure you don't have this extension installed.

Comment: Ah that is the one to disable Analytics - ok thanks very much!

Comment: @Dennis—You could also run Firefox with NoScript and not allow that script, or scripts from Google in general, to run.

Comment: Yeah, I've also stumpled today about it.
The strange thing is, that this script tag is inserted before the head tag, which leads to a non conform html markup. Google should know it better but since I got enough false positives in their recoded Search Console nothing wonders me anymore regarding this company.